# Symfony insert into a table, all colums foreign key

Tags: symfony

I want to insert data into a middle table `Builds_Perks` with columns `idBuild` and `idPerks`. The problem is with `idPerks`, I take the `id` from some checkbox and when I want to isnert those id the following error appears:

Argument 2 passed to App\Entity\BuildsPerks::__construct() must be an instance of App\Entity\Perks, int given...

This is part of the code where I take the checkbox `id` to INSERT them:

```
        $idAllPerks = $request->get('chk');
        foreach($idAllPerks as $idPerk) {
            $idPerkInt = (int) $idPerk; // string into int
            $newBuildPerk = new BuildsPerks(
                $usuBuild,
                $idPerkInt
            );
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($newBuildPerk );
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear. It expects to receive an object of type Perks but you are giving the ID of that object instead of the object itself. This *might* work.

```
$idAllPerks = $request->get('chk');
foreach($idAllPerks as $idPerk) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $perk = $em->getRepository(Perks::class)->find((int) $idPerk);
    $newBuildPerk = new BuildsPerks(
        $usuBuild,
        $perk
    );
    $em->persist($newBuildPerk );
}
```